# Out of sync between Master and Replica using Kafka

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-kafka, synchronization

I have 2 databases: Master (Java application working on it) and Replica.

To sync between them, i am using Kafka. When an entity is added to Master, an event is sent to Replica. If replica fails to add entity, then databases will be out of sync (because tables have id (sequence) field).

The project is very big and we cant use a guid instead of sequence as a primary key.

I thought about 2 methods for adding (first for master, second for replica with id) but it seems a bad way. Is there any better approach for that?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL supports streaming replication out of the box. The standby (replica) continuously receives WAL (Write-Ahead-Log) records from master and applies them to self.

A good starting point is [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/setting-up-postgresql-streaming-replication/)